# Synonym: x11, xorg

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Those of you that have 5+ on the [x11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11) tag, do you think it would be appropriate to point it as a synonym to [xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X11 and X.org are two different concepts. While an overwhelming majority of questions are about X11 as implemented by X.org, there are a few questions about other implementations. Furthermore X.org may one day no longer be the de facto standard X11 implementation (remember XFree86?), so I don't think we should lock ourselves to it.

I'm aware that X.org's overwhelming domination makes this difficult, but we should strive to use [x11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11) on questions about X11 in general and [xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg) on questions about the X.org implementation specifically. This is similar to the distinction between [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) (which is implicit on all questions on this site) and [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), or between [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) and [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash).

For example:

- How do I minimize a window from the command line? [x11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11)
- How do I make my graphics card work? [xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg)
- Keyboard remapping [x11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11)
- OpenGL acceleration [xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg)

There are undoubtedly many gray areas.

There are surely a lot of questions with the wrong tag right now, but we should try to get it right most of the time.

Comment: I had thought that XFree86 -> Xorg was just a name change, but I notice now it is actually a fork, even if XFree86 is dormant.  And of course, point taken on the difference between protocol and implementation.

Comment: Desktop X servers are not the only ones implementing the X protocol, nor the only thing related to X11 even on platforms where xorg is the dominant X desktop implementation (think XDMCP, X11 authentication, X11 extensions, security, ssh X11 forwarding, vnc servers, Xephyr/Xnest, x11vnc, xtox...)